# Explain Certbot's HTTPS redirect configuration

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

Can someone explain why Certbot is using the following redirect configuration

```
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

instead of simply this one?

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

`server_name` basically says that this config only applies to example.com, so `$host` can never be anything different, or am I missing something?

Comment: See also (both dated at 5/31/2023): Let's Encrypt Community thread [Improve Certbot nginx config generate](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/improve-certbot-nginx-config-generate/199304), and the corresponding issue [certbot/certbot #9705 - Improve nginx config generator](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/9705) (still open as of 7/24/2023)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the catch here is that if this happens to be the first `server` for this address/port combination, and no other `server` for this address/port has the `default_server` parameter, this `server` would become the *default server*, acting as a catch-all for unknown hosts.

See the [request processing documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for an overview, as well as the [`listen` documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) for some specifics on the default server behavior:

> The `default_server` parameter, if present, will cause the server to become the default server for the specified *`address:port`* pair. If none of the directives have the `default_server` parameter then the first server with the *`address:port`* pair will be the default server for this pair.

Comment: Correct. [This was actually done to fix a security vulnerability.](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/security-issue-with-redirects-added-by-certbots-nginx-plugin/51493)